# how to communicate between regular MQTT and tornado websocket?

Tags: python-3.x, websocket, mqtt, tornado

Is there any way to make a mqtt client send messages to tornado websocket?
Using this code, tornado works. While from MQTT no message passes.

```
import os.path
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.web
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import tornado.httpclient
import tornado.websocket
import json
import random
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client


broker = 'xxxxxxx'
port = 1883
topic = "xxx/xxxx"

client_id = f'xxxx-{random.randint(0, 100)}'

clients = []

def connect_mqtt() -> mqtt_client:
    def on_connect(clientMQTT, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    clientMQTT = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    # clientMQTT.username_pw_set(username, password)
    clientMQTT.on_connect = on_connect
    clientMQTT.connect(broker, port)
    return clientMQTT


def subscribe(clientMQTT: mqtt_client):
    def on_message(clientMQTT, userdata, msg):
        print(f"Received `{msg.payload.decode()}` from `{msg.topic}` topic")
        send_to_all_clients(msg.payload.decode())

    clientMQTT.subscribe(topic)
    clientMQTT.on_message = on_message


def runMQTT():
    clientMQTT = connect_mqtt()
    subscribe(clientMQTT)
    clientMQTT.loop_start()
    # clientMQTT.loop_forever()

def send_to_all_clients(message):
    for clientws in clients:
        clientws.write_message(message)


class SocketHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print("new client")
        clients.append(self)

    def on_close(self):
        clients.remove(self)
        print("removing client")

    def on_message(self, message):
        pass
        # for client in utility.clients:
        #     if client != self:
        #         client.write_message(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application(
        handlers = [
            (r"/monitor", SocketHandler)
        ],
        debug = True,
        template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
        static_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")
    )
    runMQTT()
    app.listen(8200)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I hope someone can give me some help.
Thank you all

If I try to listen on mqtt, with no tornado, it works.
I would like to be able to send messages from mqtt to browsers via tornado websocket.

Comment: Why not just use MQTT over Websockets and have the page connect directly to the broker and remove the need to forward via the Python backend?

Comment: Because messages from the broker must first be processed. Messages must be filtered using parameters from POST.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that MQTT client works using threads and Tornado's `WebSocketHandler.send_message()` is not thread safe. I don't think `asyncio-mqtt` would help because from what I can see it also uses threads.

So the easiest may be to use `queue.Queue` for exchanging messages between MQTT client and tornado worker - worker  will send it to all your websocket connections.

```py
import asyncio
import logging
import threading
from functools import partial
from queue import Queue, Empty

from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from tornado.web import RequestHandler, Application
from tornado.websocket import WebSocketHandler, WebSocketClosedError
from tornado.log import enable_pretty_logging
from tornado.options import define, options, parse_command_line

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
from paho.mqtt.client import MQTTMessage

define("port", default=3333, help="run on the given port", type=int)
define("debug", default=False, help="run in debug mode")
define("autoreload", default=False, help="autoreload")
define("mqtt_host", default="localhost", help="MQTT host")
define("mqtt_topic", default="test", help="MQTT topic")


MAINPAGE = """
<html>
<script>
let ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:3333/ws");
ws.onmessage = function(event) {
  console.log(`[message] Data received from tornado: ${event.data}`);
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = event.data;
};
ws.onerror = function(error) {
  console.log(error);
  alert(error);
};
</script>
<body>
<h3>message from MQTT:</h3>
<p id="message"></p>
</body>
</html>
"""


class MainHandler(RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        self.finish(MAINPAGE)


Q = Queue(maxsize=100)


def mqtt_on_message(client, userdata, msg: MQTTMessage):
    logging.info(
        f"thread_id={threading.get_ident()} MQTT client received message: {msg.topic} {msg.payload}"
    )
    message = msg.payload.decode()
    data = dict(message=message, topic=msg.topic)
    Q.put_nowait(data)


def mqtt_on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    logging.info(f"{threading.get_ident()} MQTT connected to topic")
    client.subscribe(options.mqtt_topic)


def mqtt_start_client():
    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_connect = mqtt_on_connect
    client.on_message = mqtt_on_message
    client.connect_async(options.mqtt_host)
    client.loop_start()
    return client


def mqtt_stop_client(client):
    client.unsubscribe(options.mqtt_topic)
    client.loop_stop(force=True)


WEB_CLIENTS = set()


class Worker:
    async def work(self):
        while self.should_work:
            msg = None
            try:
                msg = await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(
                    None, partial(Q.get, block=True, timeout=1)
                )
            except Empty:
                await asyncio.sleep(0.3)

            if msg:
                logging.info(f"thread_id={threading.get_ident()} tornado got message from MQTT: {msg}")
                futs = set()
                for ws in WEB_CLIENTS:
                    fut = ws.write_message(msg)
                    futs.add(fut)
                    fut.add_done_callback(futs.discard)

    def start(self):
        self.should_work = True
        IOLoop.current().add_callback(self.work)

    def stop(self):
        self.should_work = False


class SimpleWebSocket(WebSocketHandler):
    async def open(self):
        WEB_CLIENTS.add(self)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        logging.info(f"tornado got message from websocket: {message}")
        #def send_to_mqtt(message):
        #    publish.single(options.mqtt_topic, payload=message, hostname=options.mqtt_host)
        #
        #try:
        #    await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, send_to_mqtt, message)
        #except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        #    logging.info("sending to topic timeout")

    def on_close(self):
        WEB_CLIENTS.remove(self)

    def check_origin(self, origin):
        return True


def make_app():
    app = Application(
        [
            (r"/", MainHandler),
            (r"/ws", SimpleWebSocket),
        ],
        **dict(debug=options.debug, websocket_ping_interval=10),
    )
    return app


def main():
    app = make_app()
    app.listen(options.port)
    client = None
    worker = None
    try:
        client = mqtt_start_client()
        worker = Worker()
        worker.start()
        IOLoop.instance().start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print()
    if worker:
        worker.stop()
    if client:
        mqtt_stop_client(client)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parse_command_line()
    if options.debug:
        enable_pretty_logging(options)
    main()
```